# Is there a way get the caller IP in lambda function of a object lambda access point?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In our Lambda function for the object lambda access point, we generate logs to see who is accessing what etc. Is there a way to get the IP address of the caller inside the lambda function?

Comment: How is the Lambda triggered?  What is an "object lambda access point"?

Comment: It's a new feature from aws. object lambda access point, is like an accesspoint for s3. but all accesses goes through lambda. so that lambda can alter the s3 object before returning the object.